# How can i add element to my array under a specific key?

Tags: php, arrays

How can i add element to my array under a specific key?

This is my array output before i use foreach. As you can see, the error field is empty. I want to fill it out.

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [transactionid] => 2223
    [created] => 26-02-13 14:07:00
    [cardid] => 10102609
    [pricebefordiscount] => 68900
    [error] =>
  )
```

This is my foreach. As you can see i already tried to make this work by implementing `$arrayname['index'] = $value;`. But this does not work, nothing comes out when i spit out in a `print_r`. Why is this happening?

```
foreach ($samlet as $key)
{
    if ($key['pricebefordiscount'] > '200000') 
    {
        $samlet['error'] = "O/2000";
    }
    if ($key['cardid'] === '88888888') 
    {
        $samlet['error'] = "Testscan";
    }
}
```

This is the desired output:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [transactionid] => 2223
    [created] => 26-02-13 14:07:00
    [cardid] => 10102609
    [pricebefordiscount] => 68900
    [error] => "Testscan"
  )
```

Comment: I think it would be done with array_merge

Comment: is your if statement true?

Comment: I don't think any of your conditions are being satisfied. pricebefordiscount is 68900 whereas you have checked it for > 200000. And cardid is 10102609 whereas you are checking it for 88888888. Plz correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `foreach`, so you have the indexes used in the *"main"* `$samlet` array:

```
foreach($samlet as $key => $array)
{
    if ($array['cardid'] === '88888888')
    {
        $samlet[$key]['error'] = '0/2000';
    }
}
```

And so on...

Comment: With this solution the problem is that within this loop ``$array`` retains the old values. Not a serious issue, but something you have to remember.

Comment: @leafnode: Yes, `$array` retains the _"original"_ values, but by accessing `$samlet` whenever we're assigning something, that's not really a problem, is it?

Comment: It's not, but with that approach in a single block we have to deal with two different data accessing methods, having almost-the-same-but-not-really-identical data, losing the advantages of foreach. With this approach, I'd rather refrain from using ``$array`` at all not to confuse anyone, or even go with ``foreach(array_keys($samlet) as $key)`` - but this is rather eccentric when having possibility to use reference.

Comment: @leafnode: I wouldn't use `array_keys` at all here, but why not combine both our suggestions (that way, everybody is happy): `foreach ($samlet as $key => &$value)`... :-)

Comment: And I also wouldn't use ``array_keys``, that was just a mental exercise ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
foreach ($samlet as &$key){

    if ($key['pricebefordiscount'] > '200000'){
         $key['error'] = "O/2000";
    }
    if ($key['cardid'] === '88888888'){
        $key['error'] = "Testscan";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

So your code should looke like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($samlet as &$key)
{

    if ($key['pricebefordiscount'] > '200000') 
    {
         $key['error'] = "O/2000";
    }
    if ($key['cardid'] === '88888888') 
    {
        $key['error'] = "Testscan";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `$key['error']`, otherwise there's no point in passing the `$key` arrays by reference... also note that using references can lead to bugs more easily (as an ampersand is easy to overlook)

Comment: Yes, my mistake - I copied the OPs code assuming that apart from the reference the rest was OK ;) I fixed the code just a minute ago.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
foreach ($samlet as $key=>$value)
{

    if ($value['pricebefordiscount'] > '200000') 
    {
         $samlet[$key]['error'] = "O/2000";
    }
        if ($value['cardid'] === '88888888') 
    {
        $samlet[$key]['error'] = "Testscan";
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work, you're using an array as key... it's not because the variable is called _key_, that that is what it'll hold

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, but this will :)